# How to display Mongo DB collection in client main view in MeteorJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am new to MeteorJS. I tried following codes to display MongoDB collection in client view.

**client/main.js**

```
Resolutions = new Mongo.Collection('resolutions');

Template.body.helpers({
   resolutions : function(){
      return Resolutions.find();
   }
});
```

**client/main.html** (blaze is used here)

```
<head>
   <title>resolutions</title>
</head>

<body>
   <ul>
      {{#each resolutions}}
         {{>resolution}}
      {{/each}}
   </ul>
</body>

<template name="resolution">
   <li>{{title}}</li>
</template>
```

And then I inserted some objects to the collection using meteor mongo shell

```
db.resolutions.insert({title:"test", createdAt:new Date()});
```

And the I test weather the object is inserted to the collection using

```
db.resolutions.find()
```

And the output was,

```
    {
     "_id": ObjectId("589c8d1639645e128780c3b4"),
     "title": "test",
     "createdAt": ISODate("2017-02-09T15:39:02.216Z")
 }
```

But in the client view object titles are not displayed in a list as expected. An empty screen is viewed instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are almost there but appear to be missing the proper declarations to publish and subscribe to your collection.

You can find this helpfully documented in the official Meteor tutorials at: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're still using `autopublish` you need to declare your collection on both the client and the server. The simplest way to do this is by declaring it in `/lib`.

/lib/collections.js

```
Resolutions = new Mongo.Collection('resolutions');
```

/client/main.js

```
Template.body.helpers({
   resolutions : function(){
      return Resolutions.find();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Resolutions.find();` returns a cursor and not an array. Use **[`fetch()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch)** method instead:

```
Template.resolutions.helpers({
    resolutions: function(){
        return Resolutions.find().fetch();
    }
});
```

**client/main.html**

```
<head>
   <title>resolutions</title>
</head>

<body>
    <template name="resolution">       
        <ul>
          {{#each resolutions}}
             <li>{{title}}</li>
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </template>
</body>
```